# best sensor selection for ar application

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-sensors

Hello i want to ask which is the best sensor i can use for an [augmented-reality](/questions/tagged/augmented-reality) application? my augmented reality app is using the mobiles camera and finds points of interest in the live view. i want to detect when the poi is in the field of view of my camera. I have read a lot of articles and i want to decide which option is the best. Here are my choices:
1)Compass with accelometer
2)Rotation vector

i though that the only solution is the 1) but finally i think that the 2) is more simple to create and more accurate than the first. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, you need to use multiple sensors. I've written a POI app, and use the accelerometer, GPS, compass and orientation sensors to get the current device position and field of view.

You should probably start from the basics of Augmented Reality, before attempting an app like a POI one, as they are considerably complex.

Might I humbly recommend my book, [Pro Android Augmented Reality](http://www.apress.com/9781430239451)?

Even if you don't get a copy, you can still pick up the source code from it's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/RaghavSood/ProAndroidAugmentedReality). Chapter 9 contains code for a POI example app that shows nearby tweets and wikipedia articles.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. i am gonna read this book. i have already implemented the gps and the camera preview. i am not sure that i have understand exactly what the rotation vector do but in an example that i saw it was using both the compass and orientation sensor in one. so my question is if the rotation vector can do the job of the compass and orientation.